# How to configure Nextcloud User_Saml to supply multiply groups through request headers

Tags: nextcloud

I have a Nextcloud 25 installation with user_saml 5.03 installed behind a gateway.

My user_saml installation is enabled and configured to have type "environment-variable" and the user id is mapped to "Username"

```
    sudo -u nginx -- /nextcloud/html/occ app:enable user_saml
    sudo -u nginx -- /nextcloud/html/occ config:app:set --value="environment-variable" user_saml type
    sudo -u nginx -- /nextcloud/html/occ saml:config:set --general-uid_mapping="Username" 1
```

This works, and my users can login, but I would like the gateway to supply roles.

How do I configure `saml-attribute-mapping-group_mapping` to make this possible, and what does the gateway need to supply?

```
    sudo -u nginx -- /nextcloud/html/occ saml:config:set --saml-attribute-mapping-group_mapping="?????"  1
```

Answer (score 0):

The mapping needs to be configured with a space separated list of header names (each prefixed by "HTTP_", e.g.

```
sudo -u nginx -- /nextcloud/html/occ saml:config:set --saml-attribute-mapping-group_mapping="HTTP_USERROLES1 HTTP_USERROLES2 HTTP_USERROLES3"  1
```

The gateway needs to supply one or more of the headers "USERROLES1", "USERROLES2" "USERROLES3" (no "HTTP_").